# Mutex dynamic allocated

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I sucessfully used a static mutex, but i got problem with dynamic version.
In output a variable should be equal to zero..
Please help.
Is any better way to write this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#define N 20

int beers=20;

void* drink(void*);

//pthread_mutex_t lockk = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
typedef struct st1{
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  int val;
}my_struct_t;

int main(){
  pthread_t th[N];
  int i;
  void* return_val;

  my_struct_t *data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(my_struct_t));
    data->val = 20;
    pthread_mutex_init(&data->mutex,NULL);

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, drink, &data);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    pthread_join(th[i], &return_val);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&data->mutex);
  printf("%d\n", beers);
}

void* drink(void* p){
  int i;
    my_struct_t *data = (my_struct_t *)p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
    beers--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);

  //}
  return NULL;
}
```

Where i got fail? :)

Comment: ..  being consistent on the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem here:

```
pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, drink, &data);
```

You're passing the address of the pointer `data`, so a type `my_struct_t**`, but treating it as a `my_struct_t*` in the `drink` function. Remove the `&` in the caller and the code should work.

Please do some cleanup though. You have unused variables, define `N` but fail to use it when initializing `beer` and `data->val`, you initialize `data->val` but never use it...